# Is there a work around for number_format() in PHP5 returning NULL for empty strings?

Tags: php, migration

We are currently migrating from PHP4 to PHP5 and have discovered an issue.

In PHP4, when we used the number_format() function on an empty string the output would be 0.  However, in PHP5, running the same empty string through the number_format() function results in output of NULL.  This has a ripple effect on a lot of our code that is not expecting NULL.

Is there a best-practice solution for this?  Ideally I'd like to be able to make the change at the number_format() call so that empty strings return 0 instead of NULL and not have to check all the possible places where the output may be used.

Comment: `NULL` normally behaves very similarly to `0`. Can you please show some code, that fails?

Comment: Converting `null` to a string results in `''`.  Converting `0` to a string results in `'0'`.  This is a huge difference when you want to display something to the user.

Comment: Yes, you're right, didn't think of that.

Comment: Thanks Charles, this is exactly the case I am running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just check for an empty var before you pass it to `number_format`?

```
number_format(empty($var) ? '0' : $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty isn't the only issue. Usually, any non-numeric should be 0.

```
number_format(is_numeric($var) ? $var : 0);
```

will render anything not a number to be zero.